# Detect battery percentage applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

How would I detect what my computer's battery percentage is using applescript? All answers to similar questions say to install additional software, but I would like to do this with purely applescript. Is this possible? I've also tried searching through the  applescript library with no success.

Comment: How do You want to use the info? Because You can get the percentage using bash script like this: `pmset -g batt | egrep "([0-9]+\%).*" -o --colour=auto | cut -f1 -d';'`

Comment: I know that, but I want to set it to a variable in applescript. @MateuszSzlosek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of setting the percent charged of the internal battery to a *variable* using AppleScript.

In the sample *code* below the `batteryPercent` *variable* holds the numeric percentage of battery charge and is shown in a message.

```
set batteryPercent to do shell script "pmset -g batt | awk '/InternalBattery/ { sub(/;/, \"\"); print $2 }'"

display dialog "Battery is " & batteryPercent & " charged." buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"
```

[image]

Comment: This is interesting! I never knew you could run shell commands in applescript.

Comment: @ALX, Yes, this is what the `do shell script` _command_ in AppleScript is for. However depending on how complex the _command line_ portion is, it can be tricky.  As an example in the `awk` _substitute command_ `sub()` in AppleScript it's necessary to escape the double-quotes with a backslash, e.g. `sub(/;/, \"\")`.  If you did that on the `bash` _command line_ it would error with `awk: illegal statement at source line 1` and show where the error is. From the `bash` _command line_ it would it would be e.g. `sub(/;/, "")`. Continued in next comment...

Comment: Continued from previous comment... So you may run into similar situations where the _code_ run from the `bash` _command line_ will need to be escaped in places with a backslash to get it to work in the `do shell script` _command_ in AppleScript.